# Maximum difference between holomorphic function and 1/z?

Tags: complex-analysis

I’m trying to show that if $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $|z|<2$, then $$\max_{|z| = 1}\left|f(z)-\frac{1}{z}\right|\geq1.$$

Should I assume not, and use the Cauchy integral formula? This could allow me to determine the behavior of $f$ inside the disk and derive a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to approach this as an exercise in using the maximum principle.

Consider the holomorphic function $g : \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| < 2 \} \to \mathbb C$ defined by
$$ g(z) = z f(z) - 1.$$

By the maximum principle,
$$ |g(c)| \leq \max_{|z| = 1} |g(z)|$$
for all $c \in \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| \leq 1 \}$.

Think about what this result yields if you take $c = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the inversion map $J(z)=z^{-1}$ has a negative winding number around zero and $f$ being analytic has a non-negative winding number (by the Argument Principle) but if the functions remain sufficiently close to each other on $S^1$ then the two winding numbers must be equal per Dog on a Leash lemma.  To make this explicit, define $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$ given by $\gamma(t)=\exp\big(2\pi i\cdot t\big)$

$\big \vert f\circ \gamma (t)-J\circ \gamma (t)\big\vert \leq \text{max}_{|z| = 1}\big \vert f(z)-1/z\big \vert\lt 1=\big \vert J\circ \gamma(t)-0\big\vert$
$\implies -1=n\big(J\circ \gamma, 0\big)=n\big(f\circ \gamma, 0\big) \geq 0$
which is impossible